# Hydra parameter sweeps in parallel (e.g., Ray Tune)

Tags: fb-hydra

I've seen the recently added [ray_launcher](https://hydra.cc/docs/plugins/ray_launcher) plugin and the [Ax](https://hydra.cc/docs/plugins/ax_sweeper) plugin.

I was wondering: is there a way to launch parameters' sweeps in parallel using the currently supported plugins? Should we wait for a "ray_tune" plugin to be able to do so?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix Launchers and Sweepers and the jobs should be running in parallel if the underlying Launcher supports it (which is the case for the Ray Launcher).

Keep in mind that the Sweeper itself decides how many jobs to run in each iteration. different Sweepers employs different strategies here.

If you are convinced things are not running in parallel when you are using the Ax Sweeper with the Ray Launcher please open an issue in the Hydra repo.

Comment: Omry thank you very much for your answer! I will try to use Ax with the Ray launcher. Since I'm still familiarizing myself with hydra and I think it would be very useful for others to see it here, can you post here a snippet of how to do that?

On a separate note, out of curiosity, do you plan to support Ray Tune via the sweepers API in the future?

Comment: Sweepers are Launchers are configured separately. Take a look at the individual pages of each of the plugins.
At this time I have no plans to support Ray Tune, however - anyone can create a Sweeper plugin and publish it. It will just not an officially supported one.

Comment: If this answers your question please accept the answer.